Pyspark transform MapType Column to repeat keys
I have a dataframe which I want to transform.
Original Dataframe:
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(rules={1: [7408, 4586], 2: [9670, 2474]}),
]).show()




rules




map {1: [7408,4586] 2: [9670,2474]}



I want to reverse the key-value pair and end up with a dataframe like this:
spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(rules={7408: 1,
               4586: 1,  
               9670: 2,
               2474: 2}),
]).show()

How can I achieve this?

Check below code.
df
.selectExpr('''
   map_from_entries(
      flatten(
         transform(
             map_keys(rules), 
             k -> transform (
                    rules[k], 
                    v ->  struct(v, k)
                 )
         )
      )
   ) rules ''')
.show(10, False)

+--------------------------------------------+
|rules                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
|{7048 -> 1, 4586 -> 1, 9670 -> 2, 2474 -> 2}|
+--------------------------------------------+


Worked like a charm. I modified the solution a bit  expr= (      F.map_from_entries(F.flatten(F.transform(F.map_keys("rules"), lambda k : F.transform (F.col('rules').getItem(k), lambda v :F.struct(v, k)))))).alias('rules')
